# Class cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm using Hilt for dependency injection and getting an error saying:

`[Dagger/MissingBinding] DialogsInteractor cannot be provided without @Provided-annoated method`

I bind the class in an Activity scoped module:

```
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
@Module(includes = [ActivityModule.BindsModule::class])
class ActivityModule {
    ...
    @Module
    @InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
    interface BindsModule {
        ....
        @Binds
        fun bindDialogsInteractor(dialogsInteractorImpl: DialogsInteractorImpl): DialogsInteractor
    }
}
```

Also of course added the @Inject constructor:

```
@ActivityScoped
class DialogsInteractorImpl @Inject constructor(
    @ActivityContext context: Context,
    ....
){
```

I tried adding a @Provide injection method but still getting the same error.

Checked every dependency `DialogsInteractorImpl` has and nothing is wrong.

The weird thing is that I have other binds under `BindsModule` that don't cause any problem.

(I'm getting the problem on 5 different classes)

Thank you!

Comment: where are you using `@Inject DialogsInteractor`?

Comment: @IR42 in a `HiltViewModel` and in multiple `@Inject constructor`s

Comment: you can't use ActivityScoped dependencies in ViewModels, check [Component hierarchy](https://dagger.dev/hilt/components.html)

Comment: @IR42 Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As @IR42 stated,

> you can't use ActivityScoped dependencies in ViewModels, check [Component hierarchy](https://dagger.dev/hilt/components.html)

I changed the module scope to `ActivityRetainedScoped` and all the dependencies under it and it works.

The problem was that I tried to inject an `@ActivityScoped` dependency into a `ViewModel` and `ViewModels` are scoped to `ActivityRetainedScoped` and under.